# Why v-model doesn't work with an array and v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got a custom select component, it works with a simple variable, but when used with v-for it won't work:

https://jsfiddle.net/7gjkbhy3/19/

```
<select2 v-for="item, index in samples" v-model="item" ></select2>
data : { samples : [0, 0, 0]}
```

This works:

```
<select2 v-model="sample"></select2>
data : { sample : 0}
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`v-model` and `v-for` do NOT go together well if `v-model` is used to an iteration alias w/ a primitive value.

The Vue warns:

> You are binding `v-model` directly to a `v-for` iteration alias. This will
>   not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the
>   alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an
>   array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

Therefore using an array of objects each of which has a property for the select value would solve the issue:

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7gjkbhy3/21/)**.

```html
<select2 v-for="item, index in samples" v-model="item.value" ></select2>
```

```js
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
         sample: 0,
         samples : [{ value: 0 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 }]
     }
 })
```

Comment: 'The Vue warns:' is helpful, can not find that warning in the Chrome console, where to locate? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the idea of having to change the view model to resolve a framework design constraint. What if the model is to be sent to your backend via an API call? It would involve an additional step of having to mutate the model.

My solution to this was to create a Vue component that boxes the value at each array index into an object that can be referenced within it's slot. It then reacts to the data-changing by updating the array at the specified index via a watcher.

**boxed-value.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot v-bind:item="boxedItem"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            array: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            index: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            var data = {
                boxedItem: {value: this.array[this.index]}
            }

            return data
        },
        created(){

        },
        watch: {
            'boxedItem.value': function(oldValue, newValue) {
                // console.log('Array item at index ' + this.index + ' value changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue)
                this.array[this.index] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Example**

```
<div v-for="(name, index) in primitiveValues" :key="index">
    <boxed-value :array="primitiveValues" :index="index">
        <template slot-scope="{item}">
            <el-input v-model="item.value"></el-input>
        </template>
    </boxed-value>
</div>
```