# Vuejs reactive binding of strings in a array

Tags: vue.js

I have a plain array of strings in my data and I would like to enable their editing/adding with

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(string, index) in strings" :key="index">
       <input v-model="string">
    </li>
</ul>
```

the problem is that the strings in the array are not changed when the user types in the input.

Here is a Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/franta/74ybd0g5/10/
I would like the "Strings" part to work like the "Things".

Thanks

Comment: pass the reference instead of a value? strings[i]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why v-model doesn't work with an array and v-for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014016/why-v-model-doesnt-work-with-an-array-and-v-for-loop)

Comment: @cesartalves thanks that explains why it does not work but it does not say how to work with arrays of plan strings (using strings[index])

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `v-model="strings[index]"`

By doing this you are passing by reference and not by value. Meaning, instead of having two separate instances between `strings` and your `v-model="string"` they both share the same instance instead.